# Is it correct to add "UNNEST" in the "ON" condition of a (left) join?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

Suppose i have a bigquery table "table1" containing a column "field1" and a table "table2" containing an array column "field2"

I want to join each line of table1 to each line of table2 for which the value of "field1" appears in the array "field2"

I tried the query below but it seems to take too much time in Bigquery, it never ended actually for the cases i tested, so i think there is something wrong about it

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Tested query :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 IN UNNEST(table2.field2)
```

Result :

Operation timed out after 6.0 hours. Consider reducing the amount of work performed by your operation so that it can complete within this limit.

Comment: Nothing *wrong* it just can't use indexes. Why are you storing multiple pieces of info in the same column anyway, especially if you want to join onn it? I guess you could rewrite it to `LEFT JOIN table2 ON EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(table2.field2) WHERE value = table1.field1)` but it's probably the same thing.

Comment: Does `table2 ON INSTR(table1.field2, CAST(table2.field2 AS STRING)) > 0` work (faster)?

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, it seems that EXISTS is not supported inside the "ON" condition in Bigquery, i get the following error : "EXISTS subquery is not supported inside join predicate". Also, i store multiple pieces of info in the same column because of some other constraints that i have and that i did not mention for simplification, but i'll see if i can rework my "table2" to avoid this (even though it would've been great to have a solution for this specific case without reworking "table2").

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, i like the idea ! But it seems that using "INSTR" in the "ON" condition results in the same performance issues, i tried something like : `ON INSTR(ARRAY_TO_STRING(table2.field2, ','), table1.field1) > 0` (this is not exactly the condition on which i should filter for my need but i used it just to test this solution and it also took too much time, i also did some other tests without the `ARRAY_TO_STRING` and only the `INSTR` to confirm that the problem does not come from the first one and i had the same performance issues)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the rows of the joined table are much more than expected.
It could be that table2 is much larger than table1 and therefore a right join could be more efficent. First we obtain the final row size of the joined table.

```
WITH table1 as (SELECT 'a'||x as field1 from unnest(generate_array(1,1000)) as x),
table2 as (SELECT x, ((SELECT  array_agg(if(y=x or y in (5,6,7,8),'',y||'')||'a'||y) as field2 from unnest(generate_array(0,1000)) as y)) as field2 from unnest(generate_array(1,1000)) as x)

,helper as (SELECT distinct field1 from table1)
,test as (
SELECT #*,
(( SELECT struct(count(x) as counts,array_agg(x) as data) from unnest(field2) as x inner join helper on field1=x )).*
 from table2 
)
#gather statistics
SELECT count(1) as row_counts_table2, sum(counts) as row_counts_join, min(counts) as min, max(counts) as max, from test

#solution with right join 
#SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM test, unnest(data) as data2join) right join table1 on field1= data2join
```

1. Two temporary tables (table1 and table2) are created using CTEs for the example data. With `y in (...)` several machings to `field1` are in the array `field2`.
2. A CTE named helper is created to store distinct values of field1 from table1. We only want each entry once.
3. The CTE test is using a subSELECT to performe a inner join between field2 and field1. We keep the counts and all entries by using the `struct`.
4. Using the field `counts` some information can be obtained, such as the final row size of the joined table. Is this one feasible?
5. Unnesting the data array from the CTE test, yields all posible join rows from table 2. The right join with table1 keeps all entries from table1 and adds the unnest ones.